# What 3D format should I use for efficiently importing Solidworks parts into VTK?

Tags: python, 3d, vtk

I need to import multiple 3D solids that were created in Solidworks into VTK. First option that came to mind is converting them into .stl and using vtkSTLReader, but .stl isn't really efficient computationally and memory wise.

Are there better alternative 3D file formats which can be imported to VTK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vrml `.wrl` seems to be supported
http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/solidworks/sldworks/c_File_Types.htm

You also should be able to use Gmsh.

Comment: VTK has indeed a vrml importer, but I can't figure out how to import a vrml model and define it as a VTKactor for applying transformations

Comment: unless you provide an actual error, hard to help you here.

Comment: There is no error. I just can't figure out how to define a VRMLImporter object as a VTKActor.

Comment: See a C++ example here : https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/IO/VRMLImporter/

Comment: And a python one here : https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/2d52e7918c0ca64acfa1100371d24b648ff9fc53/IO/Import/Testing/Python/VRMLImporter.py

Comment: What I fail to understand is why the VRMLImporter is creating the renderer while there isn't any artist involved. With STL files or VTKSources (cube, cone, etc) you assign their mappers to an actor for applying transformations or other functions on the artists. With VRML there are no artists that correspond to the 3D object in all examples I've seen.

Comment: In any case, this is unrelated to your question. Please accept my answer if you consider it correct.